# Why app reactive(Webflux) don't runnig after migration to SpringBoot 3.0.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

App throws exception on startup after migrating to spring-boot-starter-webflux 3.0.3 in version 3.0.4 as well.

Logs with start:

`yorg.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server  at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:84) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:578) ~[spring-context-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:150) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at pl.lhsystems.groupapp.service.profileinformation.ProfileInformationServiceApplication.main(ProfileInformationServiceApplication.java:29) ~[main/:na] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'undertowReactiveWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/ReactiveWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedUndertow.class]: DECODE_SLASH    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:606) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.0.6.jar:6.0.6]  at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:121) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]   at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:93) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:81) ~[spring-boot-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  ... 7 common frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DECODE_SLASH     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.mapSlashProperties(UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:121) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.mapUndertowProperties(UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:105) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customize(UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:85) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customize(UndertowWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]    at`

My gradle.build

```
ext {
    mockServerVersion = '5.15.0'
    springBootVersion = '3.0.4'
    junitJupiterVersion = '5.9.2'
    projectreactorVersion = '3.5.3'
    reactorKotlinVersion = '1.2.1'
    junitJupiterVersion = '5.9.2'
}

dependencies {

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: springBootVersion
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation', version: springBootVersion
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: springBootVersion
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave', version: '1.0.2'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect', version: kotlinVersion
    implementation group: 'io.projectreactor.kotlin', name: 'reactor-kotlin-extensions', version: reactorKotlinVersion
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: swaggerSpringfoxVersion
    implementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-tools', version: projectreactorVersion

    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: springBootVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: junitJupiterVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.mock-server', name: 'mockserver-spring-test-listener', version: mockServerVersion
    testImplementation group: 'io.mockk', name: 'mockk', version: mockkVersion
    testRuntimeOnly group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: junitJupiterVersion
    testImplementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-test', version: projectreactorVersion
    testImplementation group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: awaitilityVersion
}
```

Maybe someone knows how to solve this problem. On spring-boot-starter-webflux 3.0.2 it worked

Comment: there is a possibility that a jar is corrupted, try deleting the .gradle and .m2 directories in your project and then re-run gradle build or gradle clean build to download the dependencies again.

Comment: Have you **read** the error. `Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DECODE_SLASH` is pretty clear. The problem is your dependencies, you are trying to outsmart the Spring Boot dependency management. Remove the version of the `org.springframework.boot` dependencies, of the `io.projectreactor` dependencies` and I believe you don' t need it on the `micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave` either. Remove the `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency that is included in `spring-boot-starter-test` already. Remove the versions from the `ext` block as well.

Comment: @Karim I did but It didn't help

Comment: @M.Deinum I wrote that on spring-boot-starter-webflux 3.0.2 worked fine . Your advices are not helpful. I have reason why i want to migrate in 3.0.4 but it isn't important.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it worked on Spring BOot 3.0.2 the fact that you are manually managing all those dependencies will lead to incompatible versions, which is what you are seeing now, you can fix this if you just will let Spring BOot manage the proper versions instead of working around it.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the stacktrace you will encounter the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DECODE_SLASH
```

Those kinds of errors generally come from the fact that you are mixing wrong dependencies. Looking at the snippet of your Gradle build you are trying very hard to work around the Spring Boot dependency management.

Cleanup your dependencies with the following

1. Remove the `version` from the `org.springframework.boot` dependencies
2. Remove the `version` from the `io.projectreactor` dependencies
3. Remove the `junit-jupiter-engine` dependency, included in `spring-boot-starter-test`
4. Remove the versions from the `ext` block.

```
ext {
    mockServerVersion = '5.15.0'
}

dependencies {

    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    implementation group: 'io.micrometer', name: 'micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave'
    implementation group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-reflect'
    implementation group: 'io.projectreactor.kotlin', name: 'reactor-kotlin-extensions'
    implementation group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-boot-starter', version: swaggerSpringfoxVersion
    implementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-tools'

    testImplementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params'
    testImplementation group: 'org.mock-server', name: 'mockserver-spring-test-listener', version: mockServerVersion
    testImplementation group: 'io.mockk', name: 'mockk', version: mockkVersion
    testImplementation group: 'io.projectreactor', name: 'reactor-test'     
    testImplementation group: 'org.awaitility', name: 'awaitility', version: awaitilityVersion
}
```

Now the only thing left that could be an issue is the `springfox-boot-starter` dependency, as that is over 2 years old that will reference not Spring Boot 3.